# NumPy genfromtxt OSError: file not found

Tags: python, numpy, file-not-found

I'm learning the NumPy library and when I try to read something from the file I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\Reading_from_file.py", line 3, in <module>
    example = genfromtxt("example.txt", delimiter=',')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1793, in genfromtxt
    fid = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 193, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 533, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: example.txt not found.
```

Here's the code:

```py
from numpy import genfromtxt

example = genfromtxt("example.txt", delimiter=',')
```

`Reading_from_file.py` and `example.txt` are in the same folder

I read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and I was trying to find something here but found nothing (maybe I missed something)

If there is already a thread on this topic, please link to it

Comment: What folder are you running the script from?

Comment: I used visual studio code and i did it like this:PS C:\Users\user> & C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/user/Desktop/folder/Reading_from_file.py and that was a problem thank you. Write as the answer so I can mark as the best.

Comment: That's the problem. You need to run `cd c:/Users/user/Desktop/folder/` first. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't running the script from the same folder that `example.txt` is in. `example.txt` doesn't need to be in the same directory as the script itself, it needs to be in the same directory as you are when you're running the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly your scenario, but I got the same error while passing a **string** to `genfromtxt` and I was confused.

In fact, `genfromtxt` expects a **file path** by default.  If you want to pass a string you need to simulate a file by wrapping the string in a StringIO object:

```py
from io import StringIO
from numpy import genfromtxt

example = genfromtxt(StringIO("1, 3"), delimiter=',')
print(example)
```

Returns:

```py
[1. 3.]
```